# Xcode distributed build not working

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Here is my test setting: 2 Computers (MacPro 8 cores, Mac mini 2 cores), same MacOSX version (10.6.5 10H574, i386), same Apple clang version 2.0, same Xcode version (Version 3.2.5)

it simply wont get started. When I cleaned all targets on the mac mini and started distributed build, no activity was seen on the mac pro. Under Xcode preferences -> distributed builds they see each other. No Firewall involved or similar. Network is gigabit ethernet... I even tried running with the same user and in 32 bit mode like many people are saying.

does anybody knows how to get it to work?

Comment: no, it does not work with the settings above. I haven't tested the current version yet..

Comment: Do you see anything in your logs?  If so, you might be able to use my solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111647/xcode-distributed-build-failure/7998327

Comment: Does this official document - YourFirstAppStoreSubmission.pdf help?

Answer (score 3):

You **Bundle identifier** and the Distribution profile bundle identifier should be same
Add **armv6** and **armv7** in Architectures and Valid Architectures under Targets.
Build Active Architectures only to "NO" this should be done under Targets. 
Have you selceted the proper distribution profile in Targets?
Have you tried the following one ? 
 Product -> Build For -> Build For Archiving

You can find the distribution build in **Organizer->Archives**.