# Xcode distributed build failure

Tags: objective-c, xcode, distcc

I am trying to do distributed builds with Xcode, but I see this error while building from my build server (Build Sever is the host, dev machine is the client).

When I try to do this the other way, I am able to distribute builds (My Dev machine as the host and the Build Sever as the client)

Any thoughts?

```
[14:44:47]: Step 2/3 (6m:10s)
[14:44:57]: [Step 2/3] distcc[95606] (dcc_parse_multiplier) ERROR: bad multiplier "/0,lzo,cpp" in host specification
[14:44:57]: [Step 2/3] distcc[95606] (dcc_show_hosts) CRITICAL! Failed to get host list
[14:44:57]: [Step 2/3] /usr/bin/pump: error: pump mode requested, but distcc hosts list does not contain any hosts with ',cpp' option
```

Comment: Same issue here. Currently using Xcode 4.0.0.

Comment: This may be an issue with Xcode 4. See these threads on Apple Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/413139 https://devforums.apple.com/message/360809 -- I have reported this to Apple under rdar 9228883.

Comment: i opened a tech ticked with apple and they weren't able to resolve it. ended up filing a bug report for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your milage may vary with this solution, but we've had to hack the distcc that comes with Xcode to force pump mode to be off to fix this problem.

1. Remove pump from /Developer/usr/bin and /usr/bin, just write out an empty file named pump in its place
2. Don't forget to chmod a+x your pump and distcc (in the next step)
3. In /Developer/usr/bin, rename distcc to distcc.bin and write out this distcc

   > #!/bin/bash
   >   hosts=$DISTCC_HOSTS
   >   hosts=${hosts//\,cpp/}
   >   export DISTCC_HOSTS=$hosts
   >   echo Modified DISTCC_HOSTS=\"$DISTCC_HOSTS\"
   >   /Developer/usr/bin/distcc.bin $@

Apologies, this is a quick and dirty solution.  There is probably a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart the build server and your own computer. That usually does the trick for me, also, update to the latest xcode 4